# Windows Phone 7 Merge Videos recorded from camera

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, video, windows-phone-8

I'd like to know if it's possible to merge two separate videos recorded from an app itself into one file.

If its not possible in WP7, would it be possible in WP8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible on WP7.

On WP8, you can access Direct3D from code and you should be able to leverage that to manipulate videos.
Start by looking here. Be prepared to do C++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198(v=vs.105).aspx